# How to click a ng-click button with selenium java

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing an automated web test for my job and I'm having trouble with my code. It didn't do anything
Here's the code from the website I'm trying to work with:`<button class="fa fa-2x sidebar-button pull-left fa-bars" ng-click="offcanvasleft()" ng-class="activeLeft ? 'fa-bars' : 'fa-bars'">::before</button>`

And here is my code:`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//*[@id=\"mainrow\"]/div/div/button[1]")).click();`

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the *WebElement* is a *Angular Element* so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* with *ExpectedConditions* clause as *elementToBeClickable* as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='fa fa-2x sidebar-button pull-left fa-bars' and starts-with(@ng-class,'activeLeft')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
WebELement btnBefore= driver.findElement(By.XPATH("//button[contains(text(),'::before')]");
btnBefore.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.XPATH("//button[@class="fa fa-2x sidebar-button pull-left fa-bars]").click();
```

This is assuming java syntax is right. I write selenium in python mostly.